# Result and Domain Design in F#

Tags: f#

I have a quick question regarding design and using Result.
I have read the excellent articles on [FSharpForFunAndProfit](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/rop/) regarding the [Railway Oriented Programming](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/recipe-part2/) and it actually matches my need as I need to access data in a DB and some data might not be available (and so create an error).

Let's say I have the following Domain

```
type Main = A * B
type B =
{ B1 of float
  B2 of string } // or any type, just took 2 simple ones)
```

If I do not use Result, I can easily access everything of a main:Main:

```
let a = main |> fst
let b1 = (snd B).B1
```

However, let's say I want to use create a Main using a function like this one

```
val createMain : x:sometihng -> Result<Main, 'T>
```

Then I know that to access let's say A in this main object (in the Result.Ok case), I can use the following:

```
    let fail x = 
        Result.Error x

    let succeed x = 
        Result.Ok x

    let either successFunc failureFunc twoTrackInput =
        match twoTrackInput with
        | Result.Ok s -> successFunc s
        | Result.Error f -> failureFunc f   

    let map f = 
        either (f >> succeed) fail
```

In that case I can write the following:

```
let a = main |> map fst
```

And I will get a

```
Result<A, 'T>
```

But how can I access easily to b1?
I know I could write a function like

```
let getB1 main =
    match main with
    | Result.Ok -> (snd main).B1
    | Result.Error t -> Result.Error t
```

However, I will then need to write a function for every parameter, which is quite inconvenient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write some function that takes type Main, and map it to type Result.

In other words just write a bunch of functions that operate on your bases types, and then map/bind them to your Result types as appropriate.

So whatever you want to do, write a function that does it to your base type. Then, at the level where you have your Result type, map the function to it.

So at the higher level, you input a Result and output a different Result. At the lower level, you work with the base types.